# Extruding / Bevelling one curve along another

Tags: bevel, extrude

I'm trying to create an architrave for a door. I've drawn one curve to represent the profile, and then duplicated an edge loop from my door mesh (and converted to a curve) to use as a base to accurately run the profile round.

I've used the 'Bevel / Object' option in the duplicated door curve and tried picking the profile curve, but the resulting form generates a 'flat' object rather than a 3D curve shape. Rotating the profile doesn't seem to affect the result. Picking other curves also generates 'flat' versions, suggesting the error is with the path. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Edit: Solved. I needed to apply transforms first. The duplicated edge loop seemed to have inherited a squashed scale from the door.

Answer (score 2):

Solved - had to apply all transforms to the path.

Comment: You would probably have only needed to apply the scale. That's a well known 'gotcha' with bevelling.

Comment: Good to know. It seemed to work, but it looks like the resulting extruded profile is only half the diameter of the original curve, even though scales of both are now at 1. What might I be missing?